# change field labels in shipping address in order email in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates, order-email

i create a custom email in Transaction emails with name `new sale` and in its template i have this code that create the Shipping Address:

```
<td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                {{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
```

(its part of the table)
and the result of this code become like this:

> Shipping Address:
>     firstname lastname
>     address
>     city,postal code
>   country
>     T: telephone

i want to change the labels of this fields like `T:`  to `Phone Number:`
how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change like this
Go to your backend

`System > Configuration > Customer configuration > Address templates` and look for the field HTML. By default it will look like this:

> {{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}
>   {{depend company}}{{var company}}{{/depend}}
>   {{if street1}}{{var street1}}
>   {{/if}}
>   {{depend street2}}{{var street2}}{{/depend}}
>   {{depend street3}}{{var street3}}{{/depend}}
>   {{depend street4}}{{var street4}}{{/depend}}
>   {{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}
>   {{var country}}
>   T: {{var telephone}}
>   {{depend fax}}F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
>   {{depend vat_id}}VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}

Now you can do your customization

Comment: glad to help you